# iframe shimming or ie6 (and below) select z-index bug

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-6, shim

Uhm I'm not sure if anyone has encountered this problem 
a brief description is on IE6 any `<select>` objects get displayed over any other item, even div's... meaning if you have a fancy javascript effect that displays a div that's supposed to be on top of everything (e.g: lightbox, multibox etc..) onclick of a certain element and that div overlaps a `<select>` your div get's to be displayed as if it's under the `<select>` [on this case a max and minimum z-index doesn't work ]

I've tried googling and found the iframe shim solution 
but I wanted some pretty clean alternatives
or better yet has anyone found a better solution?
since the method using iframes uses around 130mb of ram might slow down poor people's machines

Comment: I have had this problem before. I was using my own code, but I have tried with any of the lightboxes (jquery, etc).

Comment: down vote accept
 

well we just checked our google analytics and found out that 30%of our visitors use IE6 so i couldnt just drop them out so easily
okei following your opinions i decided to go with the graceful degradation for IE using the method that removes items that would be overlapped by any popping divs

Comment: hehe this problem only persists in IE6 and below anyway hmmm yah, it uses up 50MB more when that iframe becomes visible to the browser checked it from task manager's processes

anyway another reason i've found for finding alternatives are this iframe shim doesnt work with div's generated dynamically through DOM sad i think nobody really bothers

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't have to hide every `select` using a loop.  All you need is a CSS rule like:

```
* html .hideSelects select { visibility: hidden; }
```

And the following JavaScript:

```
//hide:
document.body.className +=' hideSelects'

//show:
document.body.className = document.body.className.replace(' hideSelects', '');
```

(Or, you can use your favourite `addClass` / `removeClass` implementation).

Answer (score 3):

There is a plugin for jquery called [bgiframe](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/bgiframe) that makes the iframe method quite easy to implement.

Personally, as a web developer, I'm to the point where I no longer care about the user experience in IE6. I'll make it render as close to "correct" as possible, and make sure it's functional, but as far as speed goes, too bad. They can upgrade. IE7 (though still quite slow, compared to every other browser) has been out for 2 years (almost to the day!). IE8 is going to be out shortly. Firefox is available for every platform. Safari is also an option (and super fast). Opera is available for most/every platform.

IE6 was released in over 7 years ago. IMHO, there is no reason to still be using it, other than lazy users and incompetent IT departments (or if you're a web developer).

Comment: I'd love to have the freedom to drop IE6 to the trashcan but I CANT. Most internal use applications were designed to support JUST IE6... so they don't support either IE7 nor better browsers... I'm evangelizing here http://www.stoplivinginthepast.com, but its not on my domain :|

Comment: Thanks for the bgiframe link. That's saved me a LOT of hassle. :-)

Answer (score 2):

in case anyone is interested, here's some IE shimming code.

```
* html .shimmed {
    _azimuth: expression(
        this.shimmed = this.shimmed || 'shimmed:'+this.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeBegin','<iframe style="filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(style=0,opacity=0);position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px;width:100%;height:100%" frameBorder=0 scrolling=no src="javascript:false;document.write('+"''"+');"></iframe>'),
        'inherit');
}
```

ref: [this gist](http://gist.github.com/7372) by [subtleGradient](http://subtlegradient.com/articles/category/css) and this [post by Zach Leatherman](http://www.zachleat.com/web/2007/04/24/adventures-in-i-frame-shims-or-how-i-learned-to-love-the-bomb/)

Answer (score 1):

Prior to IE7 the drop down list was a "windowed" control meaning that it was rendered as a control directly by Windows rather than the browser synthesizing it. As such, it wasn't possible for it to support z-indexing against other synthesized controls.

In order to appear over a DDL, you must use another windowed control, like IFRAME. You can also use a little known IE-only feature called window.createPopup() which essentially makes a chromeless popup. It has limitations, like unstoppable click-out, but they are actually kinda helpful if you are building a hover menu system.

Comment: I think it was Windows XP SP2 that added an extra security feature called "Allow script-initiated windows without size or position contraints". This is default set to Disable in all IE zones. This causes you to lose control over the createPopup window. Strongly recommend against using this functionality. I think the IE team added this feature because the createPopup window was being used by phishing sites to hide the real address bar.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest and most elegant solution to that annoying IE bug is found at: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/bgiframe using jQuery.

I reached that conclusion after trying for 2 days to make it work with WebSphere Portal / Portal Applications where everything is dynamic, including the fly-over menu.

Answer (score 0):

There's also the activex method, which I'm starting to explore. It requires creating conditional code to use an activex control instead of a select box for ie6. There's a [demo script](http://www.hedgerwow.com/360/bugs/activex-listbox/demo.php) showing the technique, which is [discussed in more detail here](http://www.devguru.com/features/tutorials/ComboControl/combocontrol.html).

Update: it appears that MS Office is required for the active-x control to be on the user's machine. In theory, it might be possible to include that somewhere, somehow, but that's getting a lot messier.

Answer (score 0):

I know many people suggested their own tips, but in my case, I just simply hide select using jquery like the below.

```
$(':date').dateinput({
    format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
    onBeforeShow: function(event) {
        $('select').hide();
    },
    onHide: function(event) {
        $('select').show();
    }
});
```