# CSS Menu hides behind flash only in IE (SWFObject)

Tags: javascript, css, drop-down-menu, swfobject

I know that this question is asked a lot, I checked all of the "related questions" before posting this and I tried all of the different solutions I could find, but to no avail.

I am working on a site at Site Page and there is a header navigation using Pop Menu Magic which the original creator used, it currently is hiding under the swf that is playing below it in only IE while working perfectly in Firefox.

I have tried everything from changing the wmode to transparent or opaque, using z-index on the different divs, ensuring they have a defined position, etc.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here's the "embed" code:

```
<div id="slideShow">
<div id="flashcontent">
This text will be replaced by the SWFObject Flash Inclusion.
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
var so = new SWFObject("flash-banner2.swf", "mymovie", "747", "258", "8", "#000");
so.addParam("quality", "high");
so.addParam("wmode", "opaque");
so.write("flashcontent");
</script>
</div>
```

Thanks again for your help.

Stack Overflow only let's me post 1 hyperlink initially so I'll put the css In a comment.

Comment: The CSS can be found here:http:///www.onlineuticacollege.com/david/styles/2col-2.css
And the Pop Menu Magic Stylesheet here:http:///www.onlineuticacollege.com/david/p7pm/p7pmh3.css

Comment: I'm not sure it's the problem, but I don't think IE supports the `inherit` bit of CSS anywhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get rid of that `position: relative` in the universal selector rule (`*`) starting off your CSS. That's a *really* bad idea. Removing it fixes the problem.

It does break the site a number of ways (presuming that this: http://www.onlineuticacollege.com/david/ is in fact the site you're talking about), but you should fix that where those problems occur, not by relatively positioning everything.

Answer (score 0):

Note: When saying problem in IE, make sure to say what version since there are 3 major ones out there now. I will guess 6.

It is a "feature" of IE6 when windowed objects such as flash and select elements do not abide by z-index rules. Fix is either to hide or to use an iframe "shim"

Talked about here: [iframe shimming or ie6 (and below) select z-index bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/224471/iframe-shimming-or-ie6-and-below-select-z-index-bug)

Comment: `iframe` shims shouldn't be necessary on Flash objects. A `wmode` of opaque or transparent and proper positioning and z-indexes should always fix it.

Comment: Agree w/ mercator, except the z-index doesn't have an effect on Flash Player, it's actually specifying position that makes the difference (either position relative or position absolute). See http://pipwerks.com/lab/swfobject/z-index/2.0/index.html