# Display DIVs over iFrame containing Flash

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a some trouble with iFrame.

Basically, I have drop down basic CSS menu and right underneath it I have iFrame with flash from external website.

Unfortunately whenever the menu drops down it goes underneath the iFrame.

Is there a way using jQuery , JavaScript or CSS to prevent the menu from disparaging behind the iframe?

Many Thank

Dom

Answer (score 4):

You can try putting your Flash object into opaque window mode (wmode = 'opaque'), but because of the Iframe, I still expect some inconsistency.

http://www.communitymx.com/content/article.cfm?cid=e5141

You could also try coupling this with what's known as an "Iframe shim".  It's definitely a hackish work-around, but one that Google themselves have used, sooo... take that as you will.

http://www.oratransplant.nl/2007/10/26/using-iframe-shim-to-partly-cover-a-java-applet/
[iframe shimming or ie6 (and below) select z-index bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/224471/iframe-shimming-or-ie6-and-below-select-z-index-bug)
http://www.google.com/search?q=iframe+shim

Good luck :)  @Vili might still have the right idea with just hiding the Iframe when your menu opens.  This is certainly the lowest level, and should probably happen for any browsers that don't support these other "fixes" (hacks).

(BTW, you can forget Z-Index helping on any platform or browser.  Iframes and Flash both exist on macro-layers above the normal document flow.  A DIV will never show in front of either without some finagling).

Answer (score 0):

AFAICT it will *always* be broken on linux, since Flash doesn't play nicely with the z-index directive.

On other platforms you should be able to tweak z-index to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `visibility: hidden;` on the iframe, when the menu is opened?