# Internet explorer 6 Z-index problem

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer, browser

I have a popup DIV (js triggered) which shows an image. Very simple.

The problem is, that this DIV must overlap the SELECTS which lie underneath the DIV.

It works in all browsers but IE6.

When the js is triggered, and the DIV is displayed, the z-index isn't right because the SELECT drop lists overlap parts of the DIV.

This is only in IE6.

Anybody have a clue?

Here is the css for the div:

```
 .pop_komm {
position: absolute;
z-index: 20;
height: 52px;
width: 208px;
left: 760px;
top: 239px;
display:none;
zoom:1;
 }
```

I have tried removing the zoom, and editing some of the css above without luck.

Why is this not working in IE6?

Thanks

Comment: Love when people just find this bug that we been dealing with for the last 10 years. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I can recall correctly it's a fairly well known bug that IE6 ignores `z-index` for select elements, that is, it's **always** in front of all other elements, regardless of their `z-index`.

The basic method is either to hide the `select` in question when you need something on top of it with Javascript, or overlay a `iframe` "shim" to hide it. See this question for more detail: [iframe shimming or ie6 (and below) select z-index bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/224471/iframe-shimming-or-ie6-and-below-select-z-index-bug)

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem too. The only way I know to fix is to hide all `selects` in your page. Then show they again when popup closes.

---

**EDIT**

I suggest you use jquery, but if you don't want, here goes 100% javascript solution (without jquery)

See my code in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3aHBy/).

**JS**

```
var d = document;
function showPopup(){
    d.getElementById("popup").style.display = "block";
    updateSelects(d.getElementsByTagName("select"), "none");
}
function hidePopup(){
    d.getElementById("popup").style.display  = "none";
    updateSelects(d.getElementsByTagName("select"),  "inline");
}

function updateSelects(itens, value){
    for (i=0; i < itens.length;  i++) {
        itens[i].style.display = value;    
    }    
}
```

**HTML**

```
<select>
    <option>one</option>
    <option>two</option>    
</select>

<input type="button" onclick="showPopup()" value="show"/>

<div id="popup">
    This is my popup
    <input  type="button" onclick="hidePopup()" value="hide"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wouldn't mind adding some jQuery to your project, as there is a jQuery plugin specifically designed to circumvent this problem: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/bgiframe. You just call the function on the elements you want to fix and it applies the `iframe` hack to them for you.

More info; http://brandonaaron.net/code/bgiframe/docs

Answer (score 0):

`select` elements and iframes appear over top of everything in IE. You'll need to use an iframe to counter-act the dropdowns.

http://plugins.jquery.com/project/bgiframe