# Show E-Mail as HTML Content

Tags: jquery, html, css, angular, encapsulation

I search possible ways to display other HTML Code inside HTML Website, than doesn't conflict layout of the website.

I found follwing ways on the net:

- IFrame (insecure, dangerous) [Helpful Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3797179/why-do-people-still-use-iframes)
- Google Caja (Iframe, Server Side needed) [Helpful Link](https://developers.google.com/caja/docs/about/)
- Shadow DOM (No browser support) [Helpful Link](https://toddmotto.com/emulated-native-shadow-dom-angular-2-view-encapsulation)
- JQuery html -> dom insert to div (Search solution on Angular2) [Helpful Link](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

What I need

- Separate Layout Inside HTML and Outside HTML
- Secure mechanism to prevent attacks imported code (html, js, css)
- Option to display HTML or HTML E-Mails
- Allow execution of css and js without changing the source code of imported html
- At best a solution that working on Angular2(v4,5)
- Same thing what webmailer (gmail, yahoo) are using already, but I didn't figure it out, what technic used.

For every tip or method to get to my goal, thanks in advance

Comment: Do you have any questions that users can assist you with?

Comment: I want to know all possible options to include external html secure into a webpage, so if somebody know a good way, please give me a hint.