# Nested navigation menu hover issue with all browser

Tags: html, css

I have an issue in menu display in header navigation. Navigation menu is working fine but when the user selects the device or desktop from search section and hover the css menu top of the search immediately, this is conflicting with select box and css menu and menu goes beyond to selectbox.

Please help me...thank in advance...

Comment: here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/csYjC/1728/

Comment: 1.select the device or desktop from select box
2.hover the feedback from menu
you will get the issue that is select options shows and menu goes back of the select box...Why this is happening?

Comment: can't reproduce the problem as you described.

Comment: @KingKing It's happening....

Answer (score 1):

You should try to indent your code more often to make it a bit more readable for others.
Your menu's HTML was a bit messy so I changed it a little. Have a look at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/csYjC/1729/

The menu HTML should be structured as follows:

```
<ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Feedback</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Level 1</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Level 2</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="#">Level 3</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Level 3</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Level 3</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Level 2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Level 2</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Level 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Level 1</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact US</a></li>
</ul>
```

You should modify the CSS code to your own advantage. The drop-down menu concept is what you really should be looking at.

Comment: I see what you mean. You could try taking a look at these questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6034301/how-to-make-drop-down-menu-appear-over-a-combobox-in-ie6 or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/224471/iframe-shimming-or-ie6-and-below-select-z-index-bug . You are probably going to have to use the plug-in or an iFrame. Good luck

Comment: thanks for your link but why u have given me like this type of reference link ...no help from that link

Comment: @kashinathChormale again, I can't reproduce your problem. Looks like it happens because you are using some old browser, what is the browser info you are using? (browser name, version...)

Comment: @KingKing take a look on video that's overlapping with the select box and menu...http://screencast.com/t/YDAo8XKK