# How to hide dropdown behind top menu?

Tags: javascript, css, z-index

z-index doesn't seem to work for an open dropdown.

When a user clicks a dropdown first and then hovers top menu (which is a div with position absolute and high z-index), the open dropdown still shows on top of the top menu. I want it to hide beneath the menu.

How can I hide the open dropdown? (without using javascript)

EDIT: Not possible, see [How to select options overlapping an absolute positioned DIV?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8188353/css-select-options-overlapping-absolute-positioned-div)

I have made a fiddle that should illustrate the problem: https://jsfiddle.net/9m84dv6h/2/

Here's the code (when the top menu is open):

HTML:

```
<div id="topmenu"></div>
<br>
<div class="dropdown">
    <select>
        <option>1</option>
        <option>1</option>
        <option>1</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#topmenu {
    position:absolute;
    min-height:80px;
    width: 15px;
    background: red;
    z-index: 50;
}

 select {
     z-index: 10;
     position: relative;
 }

 .dropdown {
     z-index: 10;
     position: relative;
 }
```

Comment: Not possible, refer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8188353/css-select-options-overlapping-absolute-positioned-div

Comment: ok. I, I was looking for a similar question but didn't find it. I will mark my question as a duplicate. Thanks!

Comment: https://github.com/supunsameera/jQuery.dropdown

Answer (score 0):

I think it's browser controlled item that will always appear on top. Try using some plugin like selec2 or chosen for custom dropdown that you can fully control